# image in the header

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm trying to make an equal header and footer from the image below

[image]

I saved the header and footer as an image. Below my attempt, the header was right, but the text was left without left margin and without bottom margin

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=4.3cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,arrows,shapes,shadows,fit,patterns,quotes,spy}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[fontsize=12pt]{scrextend}

%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\geometry{a4paper, includehead, top=-0.4cm, left=0cm}
\setlength\headheight{3cm}
\setlength\headwidth{\paperwidth}

\cfoot{\includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{g.png}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\chead{\includegraphics[width=\headwidth]{k.png}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}


%\chead{\makebox[\paperwidth][c]{\includegraphics{k.png}}}


\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just a guess: You want these not in the *header*/*footer*, but instead across the entire page width at the *top*/*bottom* of the *page*... is this the case?

Comment: yes, I will try here by placing upper margin 0pt and add the image at the top.

Comment: Do you want this only on the first page, or on every page?

Comment: every page. the footer I was able to do using \ cfoot, the image above can not make it stay in the width of the page, it obeys the left margin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The follow code uses [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to place the respective images at the top and bottom of the *page* boundary. This way you can still set a regular header/footer and/or change the page [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) without affecting the placement.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{k.png}}
  }
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \makebox[\paperwidth]{\includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{g.png}}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, solved my problem. I just changed the image below because in the original template below the image still has the margin and will not number, I used the \ cfoot. One question, is it possible to use some command to make the images more opaque? In the original Word template, the images appear more opaque

Comment: @MarceloRodrigues: More opaque? No. Less opaque (or more transparent)? Yes. Load the [`transparent` package](//ctan.org/pkg/transparent) (`\usepackage{transparent}` in your preamble) and then include `\transparent{<value>}` just before using `\includegraphics`. A `<value>` of `0.5`[`0.1`] would make the image 50% [10%] opaque. Requires at least two compilations.

Comment: When I put the command `\ transparent {0.5}`,
 `\cfoot{\transparent{0.5}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{g.png}}`, the image goes a little further down, any suggestions?

Comment: @MarceloRodrigues: I see [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bVEN.gif) when using [this code](https://pastebin.com/NGpXUt4r). It places the header/footer in the background with different transparencies on the two-page document. There is no movement of the images with/without `\transparent{<value>}`.

Comment: Sorry for bad English, what I've tried to say is that in the original template has a bottom margin below the image. Your solution does not have this margin below the figure. To solve this I used the `\ cfoot` command to add the image and omitted the code `\ AtPageLowerLeft {\ makebox [\ paperwidth] {\ includegraphics[height = 2.3cm] {g.png}}}`. Using `\ cfoot` the image changes position if I use `\ transparent`. I was able to solve using part of your solution and a part of the other solution below

Comment: @MarceloRodrigues: You can use ``\raisebox{<dim>}{\makebox[\paperwidth]{\includegraphics[height = 2.3cm]{g.png}}}`` in order to raise the included image by `<dim>`. That way you can still use the regular header/footer for whatever (page numbers or something else).

Answer (score 1):

Like this? I had to define values for `\fancyhfoffset` on both sides, equal to the left and right margins:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, brazil, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=120pt, bottom=4.3cm, left=3cm, right=2cm, headheight=95pt, footskip=66pt]{geometry}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,arrows,shapes,shadows,fit,patterns,quotes,spy}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[fontsize=12pt]{scrextend}

%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

%\geometry{a4paper, includehead, top=-0.4cm, left=2cm}
\setlength\headwidth{\paperwidth}

\fancyhfoffset[L]{3cm}\fancyhfoffset[R]{2cm}

\cfoot{\includegraphics[width=\headwidth]{g.png}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\chead{\includegraphics[width=\headwidth]{k.png}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution. When I put the command `\ transparent {0.5}`, `\cfoot{\transparent{0.5}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{g‌​.png}}`, the image goes a little further down, any suggestions?

Comment: @MarceloRodrigues: Not really. Maybe try `\makebox[0pt]{\inclcludegraphics{...}}`?

Comment: Many thanks, it worked out using `\cfoot{\makebox[0pt]{\transparent{0.5}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{g.png}}}`