# How to put an image at the top/bottom border of every page?

Tags: graphics

This question is related to the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235607/. The solution there, puts a given image at the top border of the first page.

How to put that image at the top border of *every* page?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%% Graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\atxy{0in}{0in}{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{someimage.jpg}}}
\begin{document}
%% Titlepage
\vspace*{.2in}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42073/134144  and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397274/134144  might be interesting.

Comment: The easiest way uses `eso-pic`.

Comment: Change `\AddThispageHook` to `\AddEverypageHook`.  Also, instead of adding `\vspace` to just the 1st page, change the margin on every page, using perhaps the `geometry` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, change `\AddThispageHook` to `\AddEverypageHook`, in the definition to `\atxy`.  Also, I eliminated the `\vspace` on page 1 and instead added `\usepackage[top=160pt]{geometry}` to the preamble.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%% Graphics
\usepackage[top=160pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddEverypageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\atxy{0in}{0in}{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,
  height=140pt]{example-image}}}
\begin{document}
%% Titlepage
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]